# Test question misunderstanding

Tags: grammaticality

I have always thought that I am rather good at English, but in a test today I made a mistake although I can't say for sure whether it is something to do with grammar or logic.

The question was:

- When will you ______?

  1. cut your hair
  2. have your hair cut
  3. get your hair cut
  4. do your hair cut

I chose #3, but the correct was #2, although at first I was thinking #1 is the correct option.

They explain it that **"have something done"** is a common expression.

But aren't #1 and #3 correct in general?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say that that is a very bad test question.  I would personally agree that all of #1, #2, and #3 are valid and correct answers.

> When will you cut your hair?

If one is assuming that the actual action of cutting the hair is going to be done by somebody else, then this is not technically correct, but it's still a phrase people very commonly say even in that scenario.  There is also always the possibility that the person you're talking to actually cuts their own hair themselves (which people can do), in which case this is actually the most correct option.

> When will you have your hair cut?

This is arguably the most textbook-correct answer, but I think actually the least common idiomatically.

> When will you get your hair cut?

This is actually what I most commonly hear (at least in the US), and is also perfectly grammatically correct, as far as I know (with modern grammar rules).  This is the option I would personally choose (as a native English speaker).

> When will you do your hair cut?

This is the only one which is definitely wrong.